# Finding the roots of a polynomial of the form: $w^6-9kw^4+18k^2w^2-6 k^3$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I need to find the roots of this sixth-degree polynomial in $w$:

> $$w^6-9\left(\frac{g}{l}\right)w^4+18\left(\frac{g}{l}\right)^2w^2-6 \left(\frac{g}{l}\right)^3$$

I've found this polynomial while solving a problem related to a triple pendulum (for context, $w$ is the frequency of a triple pendulum with equal lengths $l$; and $g$ is gravity) and couldn't manage to proceed.

Comment: The polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ by Eisenstein's criterion. As it's a cubic in $w^2$, it is soluble by Cardano's method, if you have the patience.

Comment: I tried it by this method but I got to a point where I did not know how to simplify more the expression that I had given

Comment: For one thing, substitute $w = x \sqrt {\frac{g}{l}}$ to be left with $x^6 - 9 x^4 + 18 x^2 - 6=0$

Answer (score 2):

With the substitution $w = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}(v + 3)}$, we get the "depressed" cubic equation
$$v^3 - 9 v - 6 = 0$$
The discriminant is positive, so the polynomial has three real roots that we can readily express in [trigonometric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots)
$$v = 6\cos\left(\frac13\operatorname{arccos}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{2\pi k}{3} \right) $$
for $k = 0$, $1$, $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=\sqrt{x\frac{g}{l}}$ then the polynomial becomes
$$x^3-9x^2+18x-6=0,$$
with roots
$$ 0.41577,\quad 2.2943\quad\text{and}\quad 6.2899.$$

Comment: The answers are fine, just need to take the square root to each of the three roots. Do you not have a procedure for how you deduced and resolved everything?

Comment: I just solved it numerically, you can use [Wolfam Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+x%5E3%E2%88%929*x%5E2%2B18*x%E2%88%926).